# using deleteObjects in java for deleting files from aws s3 , getting successfully delete but files are not getting deleted

Tags: java, amazon-s3

i used below code to delete multiple files form s3

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, S3secretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);        
    String[] fileNames = files.split(",");
    if(fileNames.length==1)     
    s3client.deleteObject(bucketName+path, files);
    else{
    List<KeyVersion> keys = new ArrayList<KeyVersion>();
    for(int i =0 ; i< fileNames.length ; i++){
        keys.add(new KeyVersion(fileNames[i]));   
    }
     DeleteObjectsRequest multiObjectDeleteRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest(bucketName+path);
     multiObjectDeleteRequest.setKeys(keys);
     DeleteObjectsResult  delObjRes = s3client.deleteObjects(multiObjectDeleteRequest);
     System.out.format("Successfully deleted all the %s items.\n", delObjRes.getDeletedObjects().size());

    }
```

showing successfully deleted  but files are not getting deleted from s3

For single file code `s3client.deleteObject(bucketName, file);` works fine.

Comment: how you checking whether request us successful or not ?

Comment: After deleting i am printing this statement                System.out.format("Successfully deleted all the %s items.\n", delObjRes.getDeletedObjects().size());                                                                      Here it is showing deleted object

Comment: thats just your SOP and its not returned by AWS

Comment: I am not getting error also . how can i get success from aws ? how to delete multiple files from aws in java ?

Comment: did you check in s3 whether files are deleted or not ?

Comment: yes i checked for multiple it is not getting deleted but for single it is deleted

Comment: can you share your complete code ?

Comment: can you update it as part of question with proper formatting?

Comment: same code as mentoned in top i am using for deleting files.

Comment: my file is in this structure test1/test2/text.html , test1 is constant one and it is the main bucket and test2 directory is  based on my files . That's why i mention like this as DeleteObjectsRequest(bucketName+path) , Here bucketName is constant one (test1) and path is the test2                                 In keys i am adding file names which i want to delete from  this path "test1/test2/"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below methods, it will handle deletion even for truncated pages, and also it will recursively delete all the contents in the given directory:

```
   public Set<String> listS3DirFiles(String bucket, String dirPrefix) {
        ListObjectsV2Request s3FileReq = new ListObjectsV2Request()
                .withBucketName(bucket)
                .withPrefix(dirPrefix)
                .withDelimiter("/");

        Set<String> filesList = new HashSet<>();
        ListObjectsV2Result objectsListing;
        try {
            do {
                objectsListing = amazonS3.listObjectsV2(s3FileReq);
                objectsListing.getCommonPrefixes().forEach(folderPrefix -> {
                    filesList.add(folderPrefix);
                    Set<String> tempPrefix = listS3DirFiles(bucket, folderPrefix);
                    filesList.addAll(tempPrefix);
                });

                for (S3ObjectSummary summary: objectsListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
                    filesList.add(summary.getKey());
                }

                s3FileReq.setContinuationToken(objectsListing.getNextContinuationToken());
            } while(objectsListing.isTruncated());
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }

        return filesList;
    }

    public boolean deleteDirectoryContents(String bucket, String directoryPrefix) {
        Set<String> keysSet = listS3DirFiles(bucket, directoryPrefix);

        if (keysSet.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Given directory {} doesn't have any file "+ directoryPrefix);
            return false;
        }

        DeleteObjectsRequest deleteObjectsRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest(bucket)
                .withKeys(keysSet.toArray(new String[0]));
        try {
            amazonS3.deleteObjects(deleteObjectsRequest);
        }  catch (SdkClientException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }

        return true;
    }
```